# Apply kNN model to whole dataset in RapidMiner

Tags: rapidminer

beginner RapidMiner question here. Say I am done developing a predictive kNN model through e.g. cross validation and I now want to do predictions on the whole dataset that I have worked on (train and test set) with this model, how is this done? I've tried the following:

[image]

but then each object's 'label' is included in its own Nearest Neighborhood so if k = 1 the prediction error = 0, which obviously shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it can be done by extracting the 'test set' from within 'cross validation' see below:

[image]

So basically the whole dataset is the test and training set when Cross Validation is used and predictions are also included in the output as an extra column, not sure whether they are averages or just the latest iteration though.

Comment: Ah, sorry if I get your question wrong.  BTW it is very convenient to share the XML-files of your RapidMiner processes.

Comment: No probs thanks for bothering to answer. Its a bit of a tricky issue since kNN is a special case when it comes to training/testing there is an interesting discussion on that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814731/knn-training-testing-and-validation

Answer (score 0):

you are correct, applying the model on the same data it was trained on is wrong. Normally who would have a set up where you on part of the data for training the model and then another part (which was not involved in the training) for testing.

Remember, a cross validation is normally not part of the training, but a method to ensure that your model is stable and not over trained on the presented data.

I can recommend to take a look at the RapidMiner tutorial videos on [applying](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AduZ6TurpDI), [testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMMzs5X-BNg) and [validating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hw3tVDZ4Pmo).

Also feel free to ask further, or re-post, questions in the [RapidMiner community forum](http://community.rapidminer.com).